# diviside numbers using php

Tags: php, division

I am trying to create a php code to execute a list of divisions, i have tried to put a code together but being a novice, it's not quite working.

```
<?php
$division(6,true); 
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    if(($division / $i) == $result)  
      {echo "<p>$division &division; $i = $result</p>";}      
   }
?>
```

$division is meant to be the main number, $division will get divided by every number upto and including $division.

$i should list a string of number to from 1 to 6 in this case.

then $divide ÷ $i = $result.

I am hoping for this to print out the list as shown below.

```
6 ÷ 1 = 6
6 ÷ 2 = 3
6 ÷ 3 = 2
6 ÷ 4 = 1.5
6 ÷ 5 = 1.2
```

Comment: What in the world is `$division(6,true);`??

Comment: What is this? `$division(6,true); `?

Comment: Oh... I get it.  They want to divide `num` by all whole, positive numbers less than `num`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this...?  I'm not sure what the IF statement is trying to accomplish, though

```
<?php
division(6); 

function division($num)
{
   for ($i = 1; $i < $num; $i++) 
   {
      $result = $num / $i; 

      //if(($division / $i) == $result)  
      //{
         echo "$num / $i = $result<br/>";
      //}      
   }
}
?>
```

output:

```
6 / 1 = 6
6 / 2 = 3
6 / 3 = 2
6 / 4 = 1.5
6 / 5 = 1.2
```

**edit:**  please note that `%` is usually the modulus operator in programming.

Comment: Wow, this may actually be the desired piece of code.

Comment: Thanks very much I appreciate your help. That's exactly what I was looking for. I can now also see where I was going wrong. I guess that's how we learn!